# Specify item metadata weight in Amazon Personalize

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize

Is there any way to specify item metadata weight in AWS Personalize in the following scenarios:

**Scenario 1: Weight of multiple metadata**

A video might have multiple metadata like `GENRES`, `THEME`, etc. with different weights. But we might want a model that will recommend similar videos prioritising one metadata (for example: `GENRES`) more than another (for example: `THEME`). Is there any way to pass this information to the model?

**Scenario 2: Weight of multiple categories in same metadata**

A video might have multiple categories with different weights in the same metadata. For example: a video might be in both `action` and `adventure` category for `GENRES` metadata:

```
GENRES: Action|Adventure
```

But the video belongs to `action` category more than `adventure` category. Is there any way to pass this information to the model?

**Scenario 3: Weight of multiple hierarchical categories in same metadata**

A video might have multiple hierarchical categories with different weights in the same metadata. For example: a video might be in both `action > crime > biopic` hierarchy and `adventure > western > biopic` hierarchy for `GENRES` metadata:

```
GENRES: Action|Adventure 
GENRE_L2: Crime|Western 
GENRE_L3: biopic
```

But the video belongs to `action > crime > biopic` hierarchy more than `adventure > western > biopic` hierarchy, is there any way to pass this information to the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying a weight for a particular metadata field (scenario 1) or a metadata field value(s) (scenario 2 & 3) is currently not supported by Personalize. Behavioral data (interactions) is the most impactful data across all Personalize recipes.

Some of the techniques that are available for introducing weight or additional objectives to ranking items include the [optimization objective](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/optimizing-solution-for-objective.html), [exploration weight](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/amazon-personalize-can-now-create-up-to-50-better-recommendations-for-fast-changing-catalogs-of-new-products-and-fresh-content/) (item cold start), and [promotional filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/promoting-items.html).